# MS Teams & Bot Framework: Action buttons seems to be not working on adaptive card, sent to cross org tenant from messaging extesnion

Tags: botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

Basically, we have a search messaging extension in our application. We can send adaptive cards from the searched results of messaging extension. This adaptive card has the action button to open the task module with a bit more information or an appropriate message suggesting the next steps to follow.

Please consider the behavior of the action button clicked when

1. The user who receives this card is from the same tenant

   - The user is being presented with a task module fetched through our bot.
2. The user who receives this card is from the other tenant

   - Our bot does not receive any events although this tenant already has our bot installed.

Try to understand why the action button in #2 is not firing event to our bot? Is there any way to handle the action button clicked event for a cross tenant?

Comment: Can you provide more detail of what is not working? No workaround should be required.

Comment: ok thanks. There's no particular reason why a bot should work in one tenant and not another - nothing in Teams itself is set that way. Can the user send the bot a message? Is there a way to check 100% that the app manifest is the same, with the same bot id?

Comment: Yes, manifest is the same.

Comment: Can the users message the bot from both tenants? Just regular text message I mean

Comment: Yes, user are able send personal messages

Comment: Hey, Can you look console for error or if you are doing locally with ngrok check that for errors too.  Is task module opening? or is task module content is not rendering (seeing blank screen.)?

Comment: Try removing cache, sign-out and login back in Teams. I tired and its working fine at my end.